# How Should I Find Statistically Significant Differences Between Two Markov Models?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, markov-process

Suppose I have N Markov Models of M states representing the behaviour patterns of 2 different groups (note: fully observable models, no hidden states), and have stored each model as a matrix of transition probabilities for a particular test subject.

I would like to test whether the transition probability from any one state to any other is different in one group than the other.

My first thought was to treat each of the MxM transition probabilities as a random variable, and test each hypothesis (i.e. that the means of the RVs differed) independently. The variable is a probability akin to one of the parameters of a multinomial distribution, so a binomial proportion-based confidence interval seems applicable. A correction for testing MxM hypothesises simultaneously from the same data also seems necessary.

There are three questions that I'm left with now:

1. Is this the right approach at all?
2. Should I be using a different test?
3. Should I be applying a correction to the CIs for multiple hypothesis testing as described?

I've read over [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22080/are-two-empirically-estimated-markov-chains-statistically-different) already, but it's concerned with whether the matrices as a whole are identical, not whether any individual parameters differ. There doesn't seem to be much else available on SE for this topic.