# Appropriate distance measure between two finite state Markov chain models?

Tags: distance, markov-chain

I am empirically creating Markov chains similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22080/are-two-empirically-estimated-markov-chains-statistically-different). I end up with several finite state Markov chain models with the same nodes but varying transition probabilities. I want to calculate a pairwise distance between those models. What are appropriate distance measures to compare two Markov chains?

In my case the state space are user actions in a computer system and the transition probabilities are the observed transition frequencies between different actions.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the properties, your distance measure should fulfil? Of course, you can use any distance on $n\times n$-matrices induced by a [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), but that is probably not what you are aiming at.

Comment: @TobiasWindisch Thanks for your comment. Yes you are completely right, in that I could use any distance measure that is applicable to matrices. My question was mainly aiming at whether there were some well established distance metrics between MC that consider the topology and the probabilistic nature of MC.

Comment: What are you hoping this distance will tell you about the two chains?

Comment: I had the exact same question. :)

Answer (score 2):

As the problem comes down to compare two probability vectors, I guess you could use for instance the Kullback–Leibler divergence or, if you need a symmetrical measure, the Jensen–Shannon divergence.

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course this is a possibility. However, I was hoping that there would be some measure that takes the topology of the chain into account.

Comment: The Tanimoto score between the two probability vectors will probably also work just fine  (sum(min(x_i, y_i)) / sum(max(x_i, y_i))